# Requesting and storing a users's phone number

Tags: actions-on-google

I am using the *new* Google Action development environment. I would like to request a user's phone number and also give the user the option to save it for future interactions. This is so I can send text messages and make phone calls for them. Is there a way for me to do this that is compliant with the T&Cs for Google Assistant actions?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with your lawyer, as every country has its regulations. For more info, consult this guide. https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/storage-user